# How to remove unknown error from Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created spring boot project from spring initializer 2-times but getting unknown error. I have also removed .m2 folder and one time spring boot autoconfiguration folder even its not resolved.

[image]

[image]

when i hover mouse pointer to package on second image is shows error.

> The type org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator
> cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
> files

also tried with spring core and context dependencies.

Comment: Add your pom.xml here

Comment: Solved @Shakthifuture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this project from spring initializr with version 2.4.1

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

When I down graded parent dependency version then its working and error gone

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Other options not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **spring boot version 2.4.1** use the below `pom.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Right-click** your project and click `maven -> update project`

Comment: i have tried with your pom but the same issue.

Comment: If you still facing the issue, please use the STS editor.

Answer (score 0):

`BeanNameGenerator` is provided by the `spring-beans` artifact. Make sure it is a dependency of your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://start.spring.io/ url.
2. Fill the project metdata information
3. Add the required dependencies
4. Click the **Explore** button

[image]

5. copy the XML and paste into your project `pom.xml`.
6. Right-click your project, click `maven -> update project`